# Facebooker SSH Tunnel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssh, facebooker

I'm working through some inital setup of a dev environment for Facebook trying to use Facebooker and its SSH tunnel to expose my dev site. I’m having a lot of trouble with the SSH tunnel. I’ve made sure port 4007 is open and my SSH config contains both GatewayPorts yes and GatewayPorts clientspecified.

I can connect to the tunnel OK on my domain from my browser but when I try from my facebook application it just times out.

If I review the debug information when I load the domain in my browser I see:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 5 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen port 4007, originator 99.88.246.92 port 56423
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:3000) in progress, fd=6
debug1: channel 1: new [99.88.246.92]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 3000
debug1: channel 2: free: 99.88.246.92, nchannels 4
debug1: channel 3: free: 99.88.246.92, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 1: free: 99.88.246.92, nchannels 2
```

When I connect from facebook I just get:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen port 4007, originator 69.63.189.246 port 44679
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:3000) in progress, fd=6
debug1: channel 1: new [69.63.189.246]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 3000
```

I’m fairly new to this development method (SSH Tunneling), is there any advice anyone can offer?

Answer (score 0):

when you say "I can connect to the tunnel OK on my domain from my browser"  what do you mean exactly?

lets call your machine visible on the internet GATEWAY and your dev machine running your rails server DEV.
if you put in http://GATEWAY:4007   your ruby server on DEV will see the request?

if that is the case you may have a dns issue where facebook is not resolving the domain name you put in.  try putting in the ip of GATEWAY on facebook as the canvas url.  also have you verified that your GATEWAY can be hit by other machines on the internet?